# Помощь в разборе плана небольшого запроса PL/SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, оптимизация

Добрый день. 

Есть следующий запрос:

```
select B.f_base_id from base B where B.f_groupbase_id = 123
```

План:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name                | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT       |                     |    81 |   648 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  VIEW                  | index$_join$_001    |    81 |   648 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN            |                     |       |       |            |          |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN    | FK_R_GROUPBASE_BASE |    81 |   648 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |    INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| PK_BASE             |    81 |   648 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("B"."F_GROUPBASE_ID"=123)
   2 - access(ROWID=ROWID)
   3 - access("B"."F_GROUPBASE_ID"=123)
```

Интересует вопрос, как именно происходит отбор строк?
Правильно ли я понимаю, что сначала Оракл в индексе FK_R_GROUPBASE_BASE ищет ROWID записей со значением 123, после чего полностью сканируется индекс PK_BASE  (без обращения к самой таблице) и затем через HASH JOIN происходит соединение строк, где ROWID в индексе FK_R_GROUPBASE_BASE равен ROWID в PK_BASE? Не совсем могу понять зачем тогда нужна операция 
 `1 - filter("B"."F_GROUPBASE_ID"=123)`.


Также не понимаю, почему Оракл выбрал именно этот план, а не сканирование (INDEX RANGE SCAN) индекса FK_R_GROUPBASE_BASE, а затем TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID. За счет чего план может быть лучше?

Спасибо

Comment: Что такое `base` - это таблица или view. Если view надо видеть запрос который внутри  этой view. Кроме того нужно знать как именно созданы все участвующие таблицы, особенно интересно случаем не IOT (index organized table) ли они ?

Comment: Base - обычная таблица, не view и не IOT.

Comment: Какая средняя длина записи в таблице, сколько всего записей и сколько экстентов и места занимает, какой pctfree ? Судя по всему оракл решил, что ему быстрее поднять весь индекс и найти записи по rowid в нем перебором, что бы достать единственную выбираемую колонку, которая как раз в этом индексе присутствует, чем лезть 81 раз по точному адресу в область данных. Видимо он считает, что для чтения индекса ему потребуется меньше операций ввода-вывода.

Comment: Чтобы ответить на вопрос `"почему Оракл выбрал именно этот план"` нужно знать очень много о ваших данных и индексах. Например: (ответы на вопросы @Mike) +  `data skewness`, `index clustering factor`, характеристики индексов для столбцов: `f_base_id, f_groupbase_id` и всех индексов, в которых данные столбцы учавствуют

Comment: Mike, MaxU, спасибо, но я думала, что есть более очевидный ответ. Сейчас пока так глубоко я не готова "копать")

Answer (score 1):

Oracle будет делать следующее (если я правильно понял план выполнения) в хронологическом порядке:

- полное сканирование индекса `PK_BASE`
- range scan `FK_R_GROUPBASE_BASE`, причем читаются только те элементы, кот. удовлетворяют условию (`"B"."F_GROUPBASE_ID"=123`), т.е. лишние/ненужные блоки читаться не будут
- hash join `PK_BASE` и прочитанных элементов `FK_R_GROUPBASE_BASE`
- примение фильтра `"B"."F_GROUPBASE_ID"=123` к уже прочитанным данным

Итого все данные выбираются из двух индексов, таблица не будет читаться вообще.

> почему Оракл выбрал именно этот план

чтобы ответить на этот вопрос нужно знать все те данные, на основании кот. CBO принимает решение...

Comment: т.е. при range scan считываются блоки, в которых есть значения 123, но при этом могут быть и другие записи, поэтому и нужен дополнительный filter("B"."F_GROUPBASE_ID"=123), чтобы их отсечь?

Comment: @Alexandra, в основном `filter("B"."F_GROUPBASE_ID"=123)` помогает вообще не читать те блоки в кот. __нет__ значений `"B"."F_GROUPBASE_ID" = 123`